# having issue to make an ajax call to google finance api

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you copy and past the following url to your browser:
http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=MUTF_CA%3ATDB900

it will output an string no problem. (that is what i wanted to retrieve from the following ajax call)

But if i do the following:

```
  this.getQuote = function() {
    $.get('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=MUTF_CA%3ATDB900', callback);
  }

  var callback = function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
```

It gave me an "500 Internal Server Error". I checked using firebug console.
Did i do something wrong in the ajax call?

Thanks.

Comment: googled a bit. is it js "same origin policy" issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shadow_boi already guessed, the problem is due to the **[same origin policiy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)**, which always applies to ajax requests. You need to use **[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)** to fix the problem.

See this fiddle for solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cb9c3/